# Explain this schematic

Tags: logic-gates, piezo, transducer

I am taking apart this non-invasive blood pressure monitor to see how it works. The engineer decided to use (what looks like a piezo-electric element to measure the relative pressure from the cuff, only I cannot decipher the circuit and how it works. It appears to be using a quad NOR gate to amplify the signal before it is sent to the MCU. The question I have is how is it able to measure the exact pressure from the cuff when NOR gates output digital signals?

Attached are photos and schematics.

[image: circuit board]
[image: schematic]
[image: transducer1]
[image: transducer2]

Comment: Put a scope on it when you reassemble it. U1 and U2 provide 2 inversions so the feedback path around them is positive feedback. That suggests an oscillator rather than an amplifier.  U3,C1,R1,R2 act as some kind of integrator or low pass filter and U4 squares up U3 output. I suspect this produces something like a PWM output from which you can extract precise values...

Comment: It would be useful if you could add the part numbers (or datasheet links) to the parts you've identified, and case markings for the ones you haven't.  What is LS1? What is the output of U4 connected to?
It may be that this is an oscillator, and the resonant frequency of the piezo changes depending on the pressure.

Comment: I agree with @BrianDrummond : it's an oscillator whose frequency is dependent on a property of the piezo, probably its capacitance.

Comment: We don't know it's a piezo : it could simply be 2 metal plates, a pressure-variable capacitor.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Very cool! I will have to  put it back together later tonight when I get back and test this. The sensor itself acts like a piezo element as it produces a voltage spike when tapped. I wonder if J1 and J2 are used to calibrate.

Comment: @JackB The only part I have a datasheet on is the Quad-NOR gate 74HC02D that I removed. LS1 is the device in pictures 3 and 4, unknown. U4 goes to the MCU, which is under the epoxy blob. Thank you for replying

Comment: PWM is a guess on my part, @pjc50 may be guessing frequency ... if you can update with waveforms that might be cool.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I suspect its a capacitance type of sensor similar to this: http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Factory-customize-ambulatory-blood-pressure-monitor_1239611449.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.124.IK8eqE

Comment: @SteveG Perfect find!

Comment: Hello guys, it is frequency dependent! And the frequency is inversely proportional to the pressure. Relative 0mmHg is about 71,093hz and 227mmHg is about 46,993hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diaphragm is a variable capacitor.   The resistor feedback  (three sections of NOR, U3 output to U1 input) acts to bias the gates as a linear amplifier cascade.   I think you are looking at a capacitive barometer sensor, possibly with oscillation frequency dependent on pressure.  It might also be a nonoscillating
amplifier, which would be useful as a stethoscope (blood pressure is usually measured with a pressure gage and a stethoscope).