What is the name and purpose of this part?
We disassembled an automatic electronic blood pressure monitor to find out its parts. While looking into the names and uses of various parts, I found that this part alone did not have a part number written on it. We must know the names and uses of these parts to solve the problem.

and the problem is?

sorry, it's my school subject. the text is not good because i used translator.

can you further disassemble it? What was connected to it? Just like you, we only see a metal plate with a single contact. so, what is relevant has either a) already been removed or b) is on the other side of this metal plate.

i added a picture of this before disassembled. it was covered with that metal case and nothing was connected. the other side is just a plastic board.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213075/explain-this-schematic

something must have been connected to the solder lug

The round object inside the silver box in the first picture that has a silver disc surrounded by a thin white ring surrounded by a gold colored ring looks very much like a piezo disc. Is that what is shown in the second picture?

please add a picture of the other side of the round object

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@FPEN now I'm confused: the question you link to in your comment, it answers your question!

thank you verrrrrry much. it wat hard to find my answer from that link because the translate was akward.
